# App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs?

Tags: iphone, ios

As per Apple they will not accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs.
So what would the alternative for this as iam running many apps on app store.
If i need to update them what would be the easiest solution?

See Below:-

Using Identifiers in Your Apps (March 21, 2013)

Starting May 1, the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6. You can find more details in the UIDevice Class Reference.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using UDIDs for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following thing as a unique Identifier for your app user's :

I use the method below to create a UUID and save it to the user preferences the first time the app is started:

```
- (NSString *)getUUID
{
    NSString *UUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uniqueID"];
    if (!UUID)
    {
        CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
        CFRelease(theUUID);
        UUID = [(__bridge NSString*)string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UUID forKey:@"uniqueID"];
    }
    return UUID;
}
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Although one of the standard ways of getting a UUID, this is not unique to the device. If the user uninstalls and re-installs the app, it will return a different identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the openUDID Download form [here](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID).

```
#include "OpenUDID.h"
NSString* openUDID = [OpenUDID value];
```

One more library for UDID For ios 5 above

[UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5)